Prove that sum of $\csc(2^n)$ from $n=3$ to $n=14$ is $0$
I'm having trouble proving the following fact, which was used as a conjecture in another problem:
$$\csc (2^3)^\circ + \csc (2^4)^\circ + \csc (2^5)^\circ + \dots + \csc (2^{13})^\circ+\csc (2^{14})^\circ=0$$
Computational aids including my TI-84 CE and Desmos confirmed this to be true.
The points are not equally spaced modulo $360^\circ$, so I couldn't find a way to construct a neat polynomial involving roots of unity. Also, the angles don't seem to pair up very well (tried to use identities like $\sin x = \sin (180^\circ-x)$).
The intended solution in the original problem used the telescoping identity $\csc (2^{x})^\circ=\cot(2^{x-1})^\circ-\cot (2^{x})^\circ$, but I'm wondering if there's a different approach using the angle relationships (all angles are in the form $2^n$). Is there another argument that proves this statement?

Hi, welcome to Math SE. Have you worked out all twelves angles in degrees modulo 360? How much progress can you make cancelling pairs?

Hint:  split up the sum into two parts, i.e. $$\sum_{n=3}^{8} \csc 2^n + \sum_{n=9}^{14} \csc 2^n$$ and note that one sum is the opposite part of the other, i.e. $$\sum_{n=9}^{14} \csc 2^n = - \sum_{n=3}^{8} \csc 2^n$$
Another hint: Write $\sin 2x = 2 \cos x \sin x$; then solving for $x$ and inverting we have $$\csc x = \dfrac {2 \cos x}{\sin 2x}$$ Since we're beginning with $\csc 8$ we would have $\csc 8 = \dfrac {2 \cos 8}{\sin 16}$, $\csc 16 = \dfrac {2 \cos 16}{\sin 32}$, etc. so the sum would be $$\sum_{n=3}^{14} \csc 2^n = \sum_{n=3}^{14} \dfrac {2 \cos 2^{n-1}}{\sin 2^n}$$ which would lead you to the telescoping sum.
The other methods you can use: brute force (convert all the angles and add them up, finding patterns), or using complex numbers, i.e. $$\csc x = \dfrac {2i}{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}$$ but in this case, you would have to convert $2^x$ to radians (i.e. $\frac {2^x \pi}{180}$), factor out $2i$, and prove the remaining sum is $0$.
If you choose to use the telescoping identity to verify it, please see the spoiler below.

$$(\cot {2^2} - \cot {2^3}) + (\cot {2^3} - \cot {2^4}) + \dots + (\cot 2^{13} - \cot 2^{14})$$ Note that each sum will cancel out except for the first and last terms.  You will get $\cot 4 - \cot 16384$, of which $16384 \mod 360 \equiv 4$, thus $\cot 4 - \cot 4 = 0$.


OP is asking about an argument other than a telescoping sum.

I've edited my post.  The telescoping identity is now a spoiler should the OP wish to verify.
